# Trying to convert an IP address to a URL in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

This is the code I have:

```
/*
 * This is a C# Program which displays the URL of an input IP address.
 */

using System;
using System.Net;

namespace CNT4704L
{
    class MySocketLab
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter an IP address (e.g., 131.247.2.211): ");
            IPAddress addr = Console.ReadLine();
            string strSiteName = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);

            Console.Write("\nHost name of ", addr);
            Console.Write(" is ", strSiteName);
        }
    }
}
```

It says I can't implicitly convert type `string` to `System.Net.IPAddress`, but I'm not sure what the Url I'm trying to get could be other than a string.

Comment: The `Console.ReadLine()` function returns a string. You need to construct a new `IPAddress` object from that string. I suggest a google search as this has been done before.

Comment: That explains it! I was looking at entirely the wrong place for what was causing the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on this line:

```
IPAddress addr = Console.ReadLine();
```

The Console.ReadLine function returns a string not a IPAddress.
Just change it to:

```
var addr = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Or if you want to get make sure the user entered a valid IP Address, use [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @BradleyUffner sure but there is no need as GetHostEntry accepts a string

Comment: I was just adding some notes for the OP, in case they want to re-prompt the user on an invalid address. I didn't intend to criticize your answer.

Comment: @BradleyUffner non taken, same here ;-)